# Ratingbar android setMax() doesn't work

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have custom 'RatingBar'.

```
<RatingBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    style="@style/foodRatingBar"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="1.0"
                    android:id="@+id/article_rating_value_rB"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/article_fit_value_tV"
                    android:isIndicator="false"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/article_rating_tV"/>
```

'foodRatingBar':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <!--Rating bar ArticleFragment style-->
    <style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">24dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

'ratingstars':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_p" />
</layer-list>
```

But I got the next problem:

```
    rating = (RatingBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article_rating_value_rB);
    rating.setMax(4);
    rating.setNumStars(4);
    rating.setRating(2);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "r = " + rating.getRating() + 
    "  ns = " + rating.getNumStars() + 
    "  m = " + rating.getMax());
```

The result is:

[image]

r = 2.4

ns = 4

m = 5

Answer (score 0):

I hope [setNumStars](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setNumStars(int)) is you want.

**Update**

My code:

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
mRatingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
mRatingBar.setNumStars(6);
```

Works for me.

[image]

I hope this will help you.